# Как перевести код с С++ на python?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, массивы, циклы

Не знаю C++ нужно с него перенести код на python, желательно python 3
такой код:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
double fack(int64_t n){ //fackториал
double xf = 1;
for (int k = 1; k < n; k++) xf *= k;
return xf;
}
int main()
{
for(double i = 0.1; i <= 10; i+=0.01){
double out = 1;
for(int64_t j = 1; j < 26; j+=1) out += cos(j*M_PI/4)*pow(i,j)/fack(j);
cout « i « "\t"« out « endl;
}
cout « "Hello World!" « endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: По очереди гуглите каждую незнакомую вам конструкцию и ищете ей альтернативу в питоне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто. Код одинаковый с С++. По сути просто синтаксис меняется

```
import math

def fack(n: int) -> float:
    xf = float(1)
    for k in range(1, n):
        xf *= k
    return xf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(0.1, 10.0, 0.01):
        out = float(1)
        
        for j in range(1, 26, 1):
            out += math.cos(j * math.pi / 4) * math.pow(i, j) / fack(j)
        
        print(i, "\t", out)
    print("Hello World!")
```

Comment: @AxelZel, на будущее: на Stackoverflow не принято решать задачи за других. Мы помогаем только с трудностями, возникшими в ходе **самостоятельного** решения, конкретными проблемами. Не стоит отвечать на вопросы по типу "вот условие, решите это за меня".

Comment: импортировать numpy только нужно и renge на numpy.arenge а так вроде работает спасибо!